# Can you expose the Windows Certificate Store to Mozilla Firefox through PKCS#11?

Tags: windows, firefox, ssl-certificate, pkcs#11

I found this [dll](https://github.com/secure-endpoints/kcacred/tree/master/kpkcs11) from the Network Identity Manager of secure endpoints and tried it with a current version of firefox using those [instruction](http://www.secure-endpoints.com/kcacred/instkpkcs11.html) with no success. The idea is to expose the central windows cert store to firefox and thunderbird thus being share certificates also with IE and chrome. Any ideas?

Comment: Been trying to figure this one out as well.  Were you able to discover anything?

Comment: Would post an answer as soon as I have any news, but I actually haven't been actively looking after posting this question. I also would be interested in more recent/working open source demo implementations of 3rd party Mozilla password and certificate stores.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try PKCS#11 module [p11-capi](http://thewalter.net/git/cgit.cgi/p11-capi/) written by [Stef Walter](http://thewalter.net/stef/)?

Comment: It actually this module seems to do exactly this, however seemingly the access  to certs from e.g. thunderbird for signing seems to be not quite working (that is why it is not really a solution)

Comment: @till: bizarrely enough, my local experience is that it mysteriously starts working once you've once used outlook to send a signed mail from that machine. My working theory is that there is an internal cache of something needs initialising.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [ms-capi bridge by keyon.ch](https://www.keyon.ch/en/Produkte-Loesungen/IAM-Tools/index.php) which also works with signing mails in Thunderbird right off the bat, but alas, the free demo is very demo and they have no public pricing information available.